# Recent Windows Updates and Credentials

Tags: asp.net, windows

Hi I recently applied Windows Updates to my server and all of a sudden most of my applications which have credentials such as DefaultNetworkCredentials or hard-coded username/passwords have stopped working.  I am unable to get these functioning... is this a known issue?  Any work arounds?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your approach:

- figure out what is not working
- figure out what was installed during the update
- figure out which of the updated components caused the problem
- take steps to either roll-back the update or fix your application